# Rails two forms for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What is the best way of having two different forms for editing different sets of fields of one model.

Requirements:

- I want to have two views: each view has a form to edit different fields
- I want to have one model connected to database.

I am thinking of two ways:

1 - one controller with two sets of methods like

def edit1
..
end

def update1
..
end

def edit2
..
end

def update2
..
end

Manually add corresponding routes.

2 - two controllers and "resources" for routes like:

routes:

resources :mymodelset1

resources :mymodelset2

controllers:

class mymodelset1Controller < ApplicationController

class mymodelset2Controller < ApplicationController

Comment: Have you tried different actions in the controllers.I think that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any strange thing with your controllers, models or routes, it will work 'out of the box'. 
The only thing to take care about is to parse the corresponding edit view in each situation.

You can indicate which template to render into your edit action with

```
if your_condition
  render: 'edit1' and return
else
  render: 'edit2' and return
end
```

Comment: good idea. As I undestood your_condition should depend on some flag which comes from URLs to edit: like edit_model_url(:flag=>'fields1').

Comment: Yes, whatever suits your needs. More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: Edited: added `and return`to avoid possible double render errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Reform Rails](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform-rails)

It does works really well in such situations

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).